# How to train network with 2D output? (python,Keras)

Tags: python, neural-network, regression, keras

I want to train a regression network which its outputs are two coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2).
my question is: if I want to train network should my output be separated? 
I mean should my output like this:

```
 [x1,y1,x2,y2]
```

or is there a way to stack them like:

```
[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can obviously reshape the output to add a dimension; a network could still return a vector. I think the question is why do you want 2D output - are there additional constraints on output values?

Comment: They are specific coordinates and I have doubt if I give it to network like [x1,y1,x2,y2], the network will not consider the relation between them, so I want to pass it to network like that. Am I true?

Comment: and also how should I set the setting of dense layer for [(x1,y1),...], I mean what should be number of output neurons in this? model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you talking about input to a network or about output of a network? Also, data format is a technical detail which you just need to follow; what is important is network architecture. Even if a Dense layer would have supported 2D input it doesn't mean it takes spatial interactions in account. For example, you need convolutions if you want a network to work with images well.

Comment: I'm working with images and I want to extract eye coordinates, now If I want to consider spatial interactions should I have to use conv layer in output?? (I use it in input layers)

Comment: No, I think you shouldn't use conv layer in output. It looks like an object detection task; there is a vast literature on it. I think the way to go is to check existing methods (e.g.  Faster R-CNN and YOLO; maybe there are better ways now, as papers come every day) and implement NN architecture they use.

Comment: @Panda Did you manage to solve this? I have a similar problem, but the number of output coordinates can vary..

Comment: My output number was fixed but if your output number is vary you have two ways: first , using rnn, second use cnn with maximum output you want and train it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RepeatVector` is there for this purpose (see [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector) documentation).

You want your output shape to be `(2, 2)`, or an array of two coordinates with two entries each.

```
num_outputs = 2
num_elements = 2
```

After you have added layers for processing input to your network, add a `RepeatVector`. This will make it possible to get an array of data as output. Your final layer needs to output `num_elements` so for example:

```
model.add(RepeatVector(num_outputs))
# Optional layers can be inserted here
model.add(Dense(num_elements))
```

In a nutshell, repeat vectors copy the content of the previous layer to be sent to further nodes, and each path will output an array of `num_elements`, giving you the desired output shape. Note that your training data (labels) has to consist of shape `(2, 2)` arrays also.

Comment: Thanks,but Does it change the results in compare with [x1,x2,...] ?

Comment: I know it can be effective in autoencoders, how about CNNs?

Comment: My educated guess is: probably not, as long as the locations of x1, x2 etc do not change in the input data, and you know how to parse the coordinates from the output. I would view CNNs as an effective way to learn features from images, and don't think they have much effect on the meaning of your output. Most networks eventually have dense layers after convolutional ones.