# Get a Validation scores for each type of prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

Hello I am using Keras and deep-learning.

I am trying to classify 2 types of scores (called valence and arousal). I would like to have a validation score per each type of scores (one for valence and another for arousal). However, when I compute the validation loss, only one value appear instead of two.

Here is my code:

```
# Compiling Model
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer)

# Training
train_loss = []
validation_loss = []

history = model.fit(x_train,
                    y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation),
                    verbose=2,
                    epochs=10000,
                    callbacks=[checkpointer, reduce_lr, early_stop],
                    shuffle=False)

train_loss.extend(history.history['loss'])
validation_loss.extend(history.history['val_loss'])
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the 2 validation loss separately (one for valence and another for arousal) and see if the classifier works or performs better for one of those.

Thanks!

Comment: You only compute one loss value? The `loss='mean_squared_error'` tells Keras that you wish to compute loss with the `mean_squared_error` function. Do you mean metrics?

Comment: Imagine that my output is 2D, so for every sample that I fit my model I expect two values. I would like to have 2 MSE values as loss functions.

Comment: You could use the Keras RepeatVector as suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006159/how-to-train-network-with-2d-output-python-keras)